# Error cannot convert 'int**' to 'int*' for argument '1' to 'int show(int*)'

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int show( int *m);
int disp(int *n);

int main()
{
    int i;
    int marks[]={55,65,70,75,78};
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        disp(&marks[i]);
        return 0;
    }
}

int disp(int *n)
{
   show(&n);
   return 0;
}

int show(int *m)
{
   printf("%d\n", *m);
   return 0;
}
```

It is showing:

```
error[Error] cannot convert 'int**' to 'int*' for argument '1' to 'int show(int*)'
```

Comment: heh? did you lose half of your code on the way to SO?

Comment: Have you put the definition of `disp()` **inside** `main`?

Comment: @KlasLindbäck I'd add a ___why__ before.. :)

Comment: In `disp()`, `n`is already of type `int*` so there is no need to take the address of it.

Comment: @KlasLindback: that is an answer, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a pointer (`int*`) to `disp()`. Inside of `disp()` you pass a pointer to that pointer (`int**`) to `show()`.

Just pass the pointer and not the address of it:

```
int disp(int *n){
    show(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

YOu have to catch with double pointer in Show()function,

disp(&marks[i]) send the address of that and it be catch with pointer now u r trying to send address insted of data so u have to catch with double pointer like this

```
#include<stdio.h>
int show( int **m);
int disp(int *n);

int main()
{
int i;
int marks[]={55,65,70,75,78};
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{
disp(&marks[i]);
return 0;
}
}
int disp(int *n)
{
show(&n);
return 0;
}
int show(int **m)
{
printf("%d\n", **m);
return 0;
}
```